# MS Access authentication with SQL Server database?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ms-access

We have an application whose UI is MS Access with Office16 version, the backend database is SQL Server 2012 Version. When we Launch the application, The application will communicate with the backend database thru an ID/pwd and then pull the data from the database and show it on the UI.

Now the backend database password got changed and we are getting ODBC failure when the Access application is launched. Usually how does the access applications will authenticate with SQL Server 2012? and where do we need to update the database password in MS Access?

Comment: Please add version info for ms-access, sql-server and win platform. Also, if possible post the specific ODBC error code into your question as well this helps to reproduce the error.

Comment: This question currently is too broad. There are multiple ways to connect Access to SQL server (with a DSN, DSN-less, through pass through queries, through forms with ADO Recordsets). If you can't tell how you're linking, we can't tell you how to change it.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to run odbcad32.exe and update the credentials in the ODBC connection for your database.

[image]